# Synchronizing POCO object tree with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm

Let's presume that I'm trying to build a three-tier Phonebook application, with the following entities corresponding to database tables, corresponding DTO objects, which get sent via a web service to AngularJS frontend, where the user can edit the whole phone book and save/discard all edits at a click of a button (not saving individual edits, but the whole book).

So my idea is to send all `Contacts` to the web app, then user edits contacts, details, adds stuff, deletes stuff and then send all data back to the web service on save.

```
public class Contact{
   public int Id;
   public string Name;
   public List<PhoneNumber> PhoneNumbers;
   public List<AddressEntry> Addresses;
}

public class PhoneNumber{
   public int Id;
   public string Number;
   public string Type;
}

public class AddressEntry{
   public int Id;
   public string Line1;
   public string Line1;
}
```

Is there some reasonable way on how to reconnect this object tree - `List<Contact>` or (`List<ContactDTO>` that looks the same) to my database context and let Entity Framework figure out that the Contacts with empty Ids are supposed to be inserted, those missing should be deleted, those with modified properties should be updated? Keeping in mind that those Contacts also have child objects.

I wouldn't want to write something specific for each of the entity class, as in reality I'll have about 100 of these classes (it's a parameter configuration tool with many tables of different parameter types), and the current version has more than 10K lines of code, the point of the rewrite is to have it reasonably shorter.

Already tried:
I've managed to produce a weak solution, where I forced my entity and DTO classes to implement `interface IObjectWithKey { int Id; }`, then cook up some generic thing that is able to detect adds/deleted/updates, then transfer data from Entity to DTO classes using AutoMapper, but I've had trouble with the child Lists.

Do I need to write this myself? Would using another framework such as NHibernate help?

Answer (score 1):

Either in Entity Framewoinrk or NHibernate, if you've configured your class mappings in the right way, both frameworks will be able to detect properties and association changes.

If you map your DTOs to domain objects using AutoMapper, there should be no issue here, since Entity Framework change tracking just tracks changes on your object graph and it won't care how you've modified it (i.e. by setting properties manually or using a library like AutoMapper).